# Difference between Excel.ThisWorkbook and just ThisWorkbook?

Tags: excel, vba, object, qualifiers

I have some VBA code that ran fine in Excel at my desk at work but at home it's crashtastic. Turns out all I had to do was change

```
Set shtObj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

to

```
Set shtObj = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

Anyone know why? Our organization has just moved to a SharePoint platform, which I suspect is causing all manner of voodoo to creep up, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Was the migration to SharePoint also accompanied by a migration to Office 365?

Comment: How did you figure out qualifying `ThisWorkbook` would fix it?

Comment: Thanks guys - 
Yes, the migration to SharePoint (actually OneDrive) was done with the migration to Office 365.   I have since tried this with a version of the spreadsheet that was simply on our network drive (NOT SharePoint) and compared it with one that WAS on SharePoint. The SharePoint code gave the error (when "Excel." is removed) but the file from the network drive did not give the error. It may not have to do with location, but SharePoint seems to be a culprit.

Comment: BEST GUESS and giving up: This seems to be specific to my user/profile. Others in the building are using the file with no trouble.

Answer (score 5):

**Does it work if you change it *back* to `ThisWorkbook`?**

I suspect it will, and the reason would be because the VBA recompiled itself (and didn't compile properly the first time - hence the propensity to crash).

Recompilation occurs when the version details embedded in the file differ from the version of Office/VBA in use, or there's a change from 32 to 64 bit Office. Editing the line is enough to recompile the line, so adding `Excel.` before `ThisWorkbook` was enough to make it recompile. Removing `Excel.` before `ThisWorkbook` should force it to recompile again.

The only other thing it might be is if there's a variable named `ThisWorkbook`, but then I'd expect you to get error 91, "Object variable or With block variable not set", or some other error, but not a crash.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried removing the Excel. and got the same error again ("Automation error - catastrophic failure"  -2147418113 , fwiw). I'm also getting the problem at work now so location doesn't seem to enter into it.

Comment: UPDATE: I just found that the problem goes away altogether when I move the workbook containing the code to our local network drive (not SharePoint) so the culprit seems to be SharePoint in some fashion or another.

Answer (score 2):

`ThisWorkbook` is a global-scope `Workbook` object that you can use to refer to the workbook instance that contains the very VBA code that you're looking at.

So *in theory*, an unqualified `ThisWorkbook` is **exactly** the same object as `Excel.ThisWorkbook` or `Application.ThisWorkbook`.

Proof:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(ThisWorkbook), _
                ObjPtr(Excel.ThisWorkbook), _
                ObjPtr(Application.ThisWorkbook)
End Sub
```

Outputs 3 times the same pointer address.

`Excel.ThisWorkbook` is a member (`Property Get`) of the hidden `Excel._Global` module, and `Application.ThisWorkbook` is a member (`Property Get`) of the `Excel.Application` class.

Not sure what's up with your file, but there's not *supposed* to be *any* difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I tried your test (in the immediate window after the error occurs in break mode). The "ThisWorkbook" generates the same error it did before (Automation error - catastrophic failure" -2147418113 , fwiw). The other two - prefaced with either "Excel." or "Application." work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in my particular user/profile. Others are now using the code/workbook with no reports of trouble. Yay!!?